# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid: How to access the contents with PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to access the contents of an Interactive grid with PLSQL. The only thing similiar is the
"Save Interactive Grid Data / Interactive Grid Automatic Row Processing (DML)" process that works on a per row basis.
I would like access the grid with PLSQL in a dynamic action, set a value X e.g. in row 1 column A and use this value X
 to complete row 1 column B with a value that I get from the database using value X as input.
Is this possible or is the grid only accessible in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a dynamic action that does an Ajax call to run some PL/SQL. You just need the correct triggering element and return conditions.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. This is based off a user's action? Otherwise, why not just use the PL/SQL before you generate the grid?